# How to pick a random char and double from list and output them in a string paired together

Tags: java, list, random

I'm relatively new to Java and a part of my homework requires that I produce a random string of 16 pairs of notes and duration.

I've looked up some examples and tried sifting through the provided materials in my class, but the results I find are either for a different programming language or for only selecting one random item in the list only.

I've defined the notes and duration as:

```java
    static char[] validNotes = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'};
    static double[] validDuration = {0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4};
```

The expected string output would be random, but an example would be:

```java
[A(2), G(3), B(0.5), C(1), C(1), D(0.25), …]
```

Comment: `List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<>(); for (char note : validNotes) for (double duration : validDuration) pairs.add(note + "(" + duration + ")"); Collections.shuffle(pairs); System.out.println(pairs.subList(0, 16));`

Comment: What have you tried? What result did you get?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick;

```
static char[] validNotes = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'};
static double[] validDuration = {0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4};
static Random random = new Random();

static String getRandomPair() {
    char note = validNotes[random.nextInt(validNotes.length)];
    double duration = validDuration[random.nextInt(validDuration.length)];
    return note+"("+duration+")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this would work - just uses a random number as the position value of the array.

```
Random r = new Random();

        int randomNote = r.nextInt(validNotes.length);
        int randomNumber = r.nextInt(validDuration.length);

        System.out.println(validNotes[randomNote] + "(" + validDuration[randomNumber] + ")");
```

This will give you one number-letter pair, so if you wanted to get 16 you would need to loop it.

Answer (score 0):

Shmosel's comment seemed to work just fine for me:

```java
    List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (char note : validNotes)
    for (double duration : validDuration)
    pairs.add(note + "(" + duration + ")");
    Collections.shuffle(pairs);
    System.out.println(pairs.subList(0, 16));
```

Comment: Keep in mind - this isn't random and will produce the same results every time just in different order.

Comment: To re-iterate, the duration associated with `A` `B` etc will not change